# AggregateException error in AWS Lambda

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

On ObjectCreated(All) event, lambda function is triggered, however it ends in below error message. Not sure what is causing this error, I've created policy for the S3 bucket as shown here. Error message also mentions, Access denied and HttpResponseException.

Error:

```
One or more errors occurred. (Access Denied): AggregateException
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at lambda_method(Closure , Stream , Stream , LambdaContextInternal )

at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseExceptionHandler.HandleException(IExecutionContext executionContext, HttpErrorResponseException exception)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.ProcessException(IExecutionContext executionContext, Exception exception)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3ExceptionHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at S3TestFunction.Function.FunctionHandler(S3Event s3Event, ILambdaContext lambdaContext) in /home/aniruddha/AWS/S3TestFunction/src/S3TestFunction/Function.cs:line 84
Exception of type 'Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException' was thrown.: HttpErrorResponseException
at Amazon.Runtime.HttpWebRequestMessage.GetResponseAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpHandler`1.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RedirectHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Unmarshaller.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3ResponseHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
```

Lambda Code:

```
public async Task FunctionHandler(S3Event s3Event, ILambdaContext lambdaContext)
 {
    RegionEndpoint region = RegionEndpoint.USEast1;
    AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client("accessID","accessKey", region);
    GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest();
    request.BucketName = "bucketname";
    request.Key = "username/testfile.txt";
    GetObjectResponse response = await s3Client.GetObjectAsync(request);
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.ResponseStream);
    String content = streamReader.ReadToEnd(); 
    lambdaContext.Logger.LogLine(content);             
 }
```

Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
            "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET-NAME>"]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET-NAME>/*"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?  I am experiencing a similar issue, but the Lambda works 90% of the time

Comment: @GaryWoodfine How are you triggering your Lambda function?

Comment: It's configured to fire when a Document (.docx) is added to S3 . The strange this is it works when I add some documents, but not when I add others!

Comment: I sorted out my issue, in the end it had nothing to do with triggering the lambda, that works fine. I was issue with saving to DynamoDb!